# How do I change Tomcat to output my webapps logs?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, logging, catalina

I have catalina, localhost and host-manager in my logs folder, and it logs out various things except from my webapps. This is installed on Windows. Another server that runs linux and Tomcat log webapps logs. Is there any configuration I need to change? I tried to read the docs but they were kind of overwhelming and did not point at my issue.

Comment: What logger are u using? Is there any associated logger configuration file that you can share?

Comment: I am using the default logger, I have not done anything special. Using Tomcat out of the box really. I have to apologize but I do not know what I can give you.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Forgot to annotate.